# Cannot run executable shell script on Google Container-Optimized OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-os

On any other linux distro, I can create a file with a shebang and run shell scripts like so:

```
$ chmod +x test.sh
$ ./test.sh Johnny
hello Johnny
```

But on Google Cloud Platform Container-Optimized OS, I get `-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied`

If I prefix with `sh` e.g. `sh test.sh Johnny` it will work. How can I get this to work normally?

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "Hello $@"

matt@rancher-4mmm /tmp/matt $ chmod +x test.sh 
matt@rancher-4mmm /tmp/matt $ sh ./test.sh matt
Hello matt

matt@rancher-4mmm /tmp/matt $ ./test.sh matt
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
matt@rancher-4mmm /tmp/matt $ ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 matt matt  60 Feb 28 20:00 .
drwxrwxrwt 14 root root 280 Feb 28 19:59 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 matt matt  35 Feb 28 20:00 test.sh
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most filesystems on a COS node are mounted with "noexec" flag so you can't execute binaries from them.

Some workarounds:

- For scripts, invoke the interpreter with the script as the argument, "bash /path/script.sh", "python /path/app.py"
- Mount an extra data disk under /mnt/disks. You can mount it without the "noexec" flag. Use startup-script to mount at boot.

Comment: Just add "bash"... That's a good hack.

Answer (score 6):

Container-Optimized OS mounts the file-system with "noexec" flag except "Among the writable locations, only /var/lib/docker and /var/lib/cloud are mounted as "executable" (i.e. without the noexec mount flag)." [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security#filesystem). You can verify with the following command:

```
mount | grep noexec
```

For more information on the layout of Container-Optimized OS (COS) file system, refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#file_system_layout). The 'noexec' option do not allow direct execution of any binaries on the mounted filesystem. This is because of by default security lock-down implementation on COS.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a binary one-off and don't want to deal with having another PD, you could also just mount a tmpfs device and run it from there.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/disks/scratch
sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/disks/scratch/
```

Comment: How would I do the installation of nvidia drivers and a docker run at the startup script ?  The startup script is not working for me when I try to start a docker with gpu.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use another image family, e.g. `ubuntu`.

There, `/tmp/` is not mounted with `noexec`.